# Trying to answer respond to a craiglists ad

Tags: email

I was trying to answer ad on craiglist and it went to outlook, not knowing what do do I hit continue with no email.  So now I have know way of responding,  How do I fix this problem??????

Comment: To clarify, you clicked a link on Craigslist, and Outlook opened, but you haven't set it up for your email? How do you send and receive email?

Answer (score 1):

When you click an email in your browser, it opens up whatever mail program is on your computer.

I'm assuming you'd rather use gmail, yahoo, etc..?  If so, then the best thing to do is `right-click` on the email address on Craigslist and copy the email address to clipboard.  Then, start a new email in gmail, yahoo, or whatever and `right-click` in the To: field and click Paste.

Answer (score 1):

To respond to a Craigslist ad, highlight and copy the email address from the ad. Then, paste it into a new email from within webmail provider, or whatever you typically use for email.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to use Gmail you can [make it your default email client](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=10966) for sending email when you click on a `mailto` link.

This would allow you to click your link in craigslist and a new email ready to compose via Gmail would launch.